# How to find oldest person using loops in Person Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programing I need to write a code that finds the oldest person in Person Array. Please help.  The program compiled but did not execute. it gave me only the size of the Array but not the oldest person. I would appreciate any help. 
My code is bellow:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PersonCollection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> aList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    // Create 5 new Person  objects and output their data
    Person person1 = new Person("Diana", "Rockman", 38, 'F', "603-28-5324");
    Person person2 = new Person("Arthur","Montgamery", 49, 'M',"402-23-5463");
    Person person3 = new Person("Kim", "Balcer", 35, 'F',"607-34-5463");
    Person person4 = new Person("Ghaffar","Kucher", 36, 'M',"537-52-6324");
    Person person5 = new Person("Zach","Boot", 19, 'M', "732-65-7364");
    aList.add(person1);
    aList.add(person2);
    aList.add(person3);
    aList.add(person4);
    aList.add(person5);
    System.out.println("The size of the list is:" + aList.size());
}
public static void oldestPerson(String[] names, int[] ages)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int oldest = ages[0];
        for ( int i=0; i < ages.length; i++)
        {

            if(ages[i] > oldest)
            {index = i;
                oldest = ages[i];
            }

            System.out.println("Person" + names[index] + "is the oldest:" +     ages    [index]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You never call the method `oldestPerson`

Comment: Can you post the source code of the `person` class?

Comment: Can you show us Person class?

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not able to upload my person class but age and name are private and I have getter methods for age and name.  Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `oldestPerson` method anywhere (better to call it `findOldestPerson`). Further you should design that method to take a `List<Person>` as a parameter.

This might help:

```java
public static void findOldestPerson(List<Person> persons) {
    Person oldest = null;
    for (Person p : persons) {
        if (oldest == null || p.getAge() > oldest.getAge()) oldest = p;
    }
    // Do something with the oldest person.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this and again compiled without any problems but it didn't execute again. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I got this error C:\Users\owner\Documents\PersonCollection.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
  findOldestPerson(List<Person>); for this code
                               ^       findOldestPerson(List<Person>);} public static void findOldestPerson(List<Person> persons)
{Person oldest = null;
     for (Person p : persons)
     {
      if(oldest==null || p.getAge() > oldest.getAge())

       oldest = p;



      System.out.println("Person" + p.getFullName() + "is the oldest:" + p.getAge());
}
    }
   }

Comment: @user3316776 Calling `findOldestPerson(List<Person>);` is not valid. You should use `findOldestPerson(aList);`

Comment: Ok I made this change then the error was that List<Person> in public static void findOldestPerson(List<Person> persons) cant find the variable List. I changed it to ArrayList<person> and it compiled but when I executed it printed all five persons being the oldest :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, that could be fixed by a simple `import java.util.List;`. You putted the `System.out.println` inside the for, but it must be outside.

Comment: If I take System.out.println outside the for it doesn't recognize the variable p my code for System.out.println is    System.out.println("Person" + p.getFullName() + "is the oldest:" + p.getAge());

Comment: You should not use `p` in that place, use `oldest` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I imported the java.util.List and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8...

```
public class PersonTest {
    public static class Person {
        public String first;
        public String last;
        public int age;
        public char gender;
        public String ssn;

        public Person(String first, String last, int age, char gender, String ssn) {
            this.first = first;
            this.last = last;
            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.ssn = ssn;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> aList = Arrays.asList(
                new Person("Diana", "Rockman", 38, 'F', "603-28-5324"),
                new Person("Arthur","Montgamery", 49, 'M',"402-23-5463"),
                new Person("Kim", "Balcer", 35, 'F',"607-34-5463"),
                new Person("Ghaffar","Kucher", 36, 'M',"537-52-6324"),
                new Person("Zach","Boot", 19, 'M', "732-65-7364"));

        Person oldest = aList.stream().max((a,b) -> a.age - b.age).get();
        System.out.println(String.format("The oldest person is %s %s", oldest.first, oldest.last));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but I don't understand it. I am very new to programming

Answer (score 0):

After `System.out.println("The size of the list is:" + aList.size());`

you must add a call to yours `oldestPerson` method, and you can update your method in this way:

```
public static void oldestPerson(ArrayList<Person> aList)
    {
        Person oldest = new Person();
        for (Person p : aList)
        {

            if(p.getAge() > oldest.getAge())
            {
                oldest = p;
            }

            System.out.println("Person" + p.getName() + "is the oldest:" +   p.getAge());
}
```

I used a **getter** method, because I think that **attributes** about `Person` class are `private`, but if they are `public`, you can do: `p.age` or `p.name`..

Comment: Thank you so much! I made the corrections but it still didn't work it compiled but it didn't execute this is what I have now:

Comment: public static void oldestPerson(ArrayList<Person> aList)
    {
Person oldest= null;
for (Person p : aList)
{
if(p.getAge() > oldest.getAge())
{
oldest = p;
      }
    System.out.println("Person" + p.getFullName() + "is the oldest:" + p.getAge());
     }
    }

Comment: C:\Users\owner\Documents\PersonCollection.java:56: error: variable oldest might not have been initialized
    if(p.getAge() > oldest.getAge())
                    ^

Comment: That's right.. You have reason.. I edit my anser, you do: Person oldest = new Person();